# GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter doesn't seem to work with layered filters

Tags: ios, iphone, gpuimage

I have layered filters that all look great with the images I am using but if I change the Gaussian Blur parameters either higher or lower there is no visible difference in the blurring effect. What am I doing wrong ?

Here is my code :

```
GPUImageView *finalView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *topLayer = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Glass.png"];
    UIImage *baseLayer = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BasePhoto.png"];

    GPUImagePicture *stillImageSourceTop = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:topLayer];
    GPUImagePicture *stillImageSourceBottom = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:baseLayer];

    GPUImageScreenBlendFilter *screenBlendFilter = [[GPUImageScreenBlendFilter alloc] init];
    GPUImageBrightnessFilter *brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
    GPUImageContrastFilter *contrastFilter = [[GPUImageContrastFilter alloc] init];
    GPUImageSaturationFilter *saturationFilter = [[GPUImageSaturationFilter alloc] init];
    GPUImageColorMatrixFilter *colorMatrixFilter = [[GPUImageColorMatrixFilter alloc] init];
    GPUImageOpacityFilter *opacityFilter = [[GPUImageOpacityFilter alloc] init];
    opacityFilter.opacity = 0;

    GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter *blurFilter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc]init];
    blurFilter.texelSpacingMultiplier = 4.0;
    blurFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 200.0;
    blurFilter.blurPasses = 4;


    [stillImageSourceTop addTarget:brightnessFilter];
    [brightnessFilter addTarget:contrastFilter];
    [contrastFilter addTarget:saturationFilter];
    [saturationFilter addTarget:colorMatrixFilter];
    [colorMatrixFilter addTarget:blurFilter];
    [blurFilter addTarget:opacityFilter];

    [stillImageSourceTop processImage]; 
    [opacityFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];

    UIImage *topLayerImage = [opacityFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
    GPUImagePicture *stillImageSourceTopWithFilters = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:topLayerImage];

    [stillImageSourceBottom addTarget:screenBlendFilter];
    [stillImageSourceTopWithFilters addTarget:screenBlendFilter];
    [screenBlendFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];

    [stillImageSourceBottom processImage];

    UIImage *mergedlayeredimage = [screenBlendFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
   [finalImageView setImage:mergedlayeredimage];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's because most of the filters in that above don't actually do anything. The only filter you've wired up is the screenBlendFilter, where you have your source images both going into it and then you pull the one image out of it. You never actually use the blur for anything there, so of course it won't affect the output any.

Comment: How would I wire them up ? I am trying to apply all those filters to the topLayer and then blend it with the baseLayer using the screen blend filter.

Comment: @JoelParker - Images flow from sources to targets. If you want something to take the output from a filter as an input, you have to target the source to the output. You've only done that properly for one filter in the above, the screenBlendFilter, which takes both images as inputs and then you extract the single image output. If you want the others to be processed, you need to build a chain of them by targeting things properly.

Comment: That is what confuses me because I thought this was chaining filters as you described: `[stillImageSourceTop addTarget:brightnessFilter];
    [brightnessFilter addTarget:contrastFilter];                       
    [contrastFilter addTarget:saturationFilter];
    [saturationFilter addTarget:colorMatrixFilter];
    [colorMatrixFilter addTarget:blurFilter];
    [blurFilter addTarget:opacityFilter];`   Taking the top images and then chaining the output of the filter to the next ... What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @JoelParker - And then you don't do anything with that chain. The screenBlendFilter only takes in the source images, and you pull the output from that. The other chain you set up leads nowhere. I find that it helps to diagram this for more complex chains, where you can clearly see the missing connections.

Comment: I modified the code in the original post to accomplish what I thought you were talking about but it is still not working can you give me a small example of how to do this. Create a picture add a blur filter or something then use it in a blend filter.